# VBA Macro loops through sheets and applies format, but misses things on the last sheet

Tags: excel, vba

OK, I have a macro that loops through all the files in a directory, and in each file it loops through the sheets and applies a bunch of formatting and such.

the only problem I have is on the last sheet of each file some of the formatting isn't changing. the other pages are fine. In case it's relevant, the first sheet in all the files is named "TOC", and then there are between 1 & 3 additional sheets that have the same columns and type of data on them.

specifically, it's the page orientation (needs to change to landscape) and some other relate page setup details.

Here's the relevant code:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
           
For Each ws In Sheets
    ws.Activate
'''apply format to first sheet'''   
    If ws.Name = "TOC" Then
        With ws.PageSetup
            .LeftFooter = "&""-,Bold"" Confidential"
            .CenterFooter = "&D"
            .RightFooter = "Page &P of &N"
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .PrintHeadings = False
            .PrintGridlines = False
            .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
            .PrintQuality = 600
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .CenterVertically = False
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Draft = False
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
            .Order = xlDownThenOver
            .BlackAndWhite = False
            .Zoom = 100
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
            .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
            .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
            .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
            .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        End With
    Else
'''apply format to other sheets'''
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
        Application.PrintCommunication = True
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
            With ws.PageSetup
                .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$2"
                .PrintTitleColumns = ""
                .LeftFooter = "&""-,Bold"" Confidential"
                .CenterFooter = "&D"
                .RightFooter = "Page &P of &N"
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''this section does not get applied to the last worksheet''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
                .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
                .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                .PrintHeadings = False
                .PrintGridlines = False
                .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
                .PrintQuality = 600
                .CenterHorizontally = True
                .CenterVertically = True
                .Orientation = xlLandscape
                .Draft = False
                .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
                .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
                .Order = xlDownThenOver
                .BlackAndWhite = False
                .Zoom = 100
                .FitToPagesWide = 1
                .FitToPagesTall = 0
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
                .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
                .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
                .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
                .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
                .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
                .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
                .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
            End With
    End If
Next ws
    
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each ws In Sheets` - are you dealing with a specific workbook here? I don't see any code related to looping through files in a folder?

Comment: Try adding `Application.PrintCommunication = True` after last `End With`